# Gnome's libgda and SQL injections

Tags: sql, c, code-injection, gnome

I'um using Gnome Data Access (libgda) to access a database in a C program.
I use the GdaSqlBuilder to build my queries.
Here is an exemple code for adding an equal condition on a field for a request :

```
GdaSqlBuilderId add_equal_condition(char* m_name, GValue* m_value)
{
    GdaSqlBuilderId name, value, condition;
    name = gda_sql_builder_add_id(builder, m_name);
    value = gda_sql_builder_add_expr_value(builder, NULL, m_value);
    condition = gda_sql_builder_add_cond(builder, GDA_SQL_OPERATOR_TYPE_EQUAL, name, value, 0);
    return condition;
}
```

Does libgda protect itself against SQL injections or do I need to sanitize the input myself before I pass it to GDA ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the foreword:

> When creating an SQL string which contains values (literals), one can
>   be tempted (as it is the easiest solution) to create a string
>   containing the values themselves, execute that statement and apply the
>   same process the next time the same statement needs to be executed
>   with different values. This approach has two major flaws outlined
>   below which is why Libgda recommends using variables in statements
>   (also known as parameters or place holders) and reusing the same
>   GdaStatement object when only the variable's values change.

https://developer.gnome.org/libgda/unstable/ch06s03.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am still wondering if using the GdaSqlBuilder is as safe as using place holders to generate my queries. I don't use any literals and I do not use a parser to generate my query.

Comment: As per the manual [`gda_sql_builder_get_statement`](https://developer.gnome.org/libgda/unstable/GdaSqlBuilder.html) returns a `GdaStatement` so as long as no literal values are passed you will be ok.  Inspect the returned object to verify how the parameters are rendered.

Answer (score -1):

Even if the current version is not vulnerable, that does not mean that every future version will not be vulnerable. You should always, without any exception,  take care of what a user provides.

Same goes for interfaces from other systems of any kind. This is not limited to SQLi and not a question of SQLi or the libraries you use. You are responsible that a user can only enter the kind data that you want him/her to enter or reject it otherwise. You can not rely on other code to do that for you.

Generally: Nothing can protect itself completly against a certain type of attack. It will always be limited to the attackvectors known at the time of writing.

Comment: This is a bit too generic and doesn't really address the OP's specific question which is about whether he/she needs to sanitise SQL passed to  libgda.

Comment: Yes. Because there is no question "if" you need to do so. I would completely agree if the question would have been "how", "why", "where", all but not "if". If someone has the knowledge that there is such a thing like SQLi and is aware that it might harm his/her security, then why in the world would anybdy not sanitize the input?